# Making objects into array

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a JSON object as follows:

```
    {
        "PROMO": {
            "ID": 1,
            "NAME": "PROMO ONE",
            "BUNDLES": {
                "0": {
                    "BUNDLE": {
                        "BUNDLE_ID": 1,
                        "BUNDLE_NAME": "BUNDLE ONE"
                    },
                    "ARTICLE": {
                        "ARTICLE_IDS": "550,398,475"
                    }
                },
                "1": {
                    "BUNDLE": {
                        "BUNDLE_ID": 1,
                        "BUNDLE_NAME": "BUNDLE ONE"                    
                    },
                    "ARTICLE": {
                        "ARTICLE_IDS": "125,250,323"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to do, combine `BUNDLE` and `ARTICLE` object then push into `BUNDLES` array. I tried many way but no success to combine two object.

For instance, I tried following:

```
var BUNDLES = [];
var BUNDLE = {};
var ARTICLE = {};

BUNDLE.BUNDLE_ID = 1;
BUNDLE.BUNDLE_NAME = "BUNDLE ONE";
ARTICLE.ARTICLE_IDS = "550,398,475";

// here, I want to combine ARTICLE and BUNDLE then push into array
BUNDLES.push(BUNDLE)
```

Comment: What did you try? What was the problem?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: As above JSON object, I made manually that JSON object.

Comment: If that is the output then what does the input look like?

Comment: inputs are form and grid values.

Comment: i hope this is wat u want>>>> BUNDLES.push({"BUNDLE" : BUNDLE, "ARTICLE" : ARTICLE});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do ya. Probably there's a neater way but this does what you want I hope.

http://jsfiddle.net/558BN/

```
var json =    {
        "PROMO": {
            "ID": 1,
            "NAME": "PROMO ONE",
            "BUNDLES": {
                "0": {
                    "BUNDLE": {
                        "BUNDLE_ID": 1,
                        "BUNDLE_NAME": "BUNDLE ONE"
                    },
                    "ARTICLE": {
                        "ARTICLE_IDS": "550,398,475"
                    }
                },
                "1": {
                    "BUNDLE": {
                        "BUNDLE_ID": 1,
                        "BUNDLE_NAME": "BUNDLE ONE"                    
                    },
                    "ARTICLE": {
                        "ARTICLE_IDS": "125,250,323"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

var array = [];
for(var i in json.PROMO.BUNDLES){
    var obj = {};
    for(var j in json.PROMO.BUNDLES[i]){
        obj[j] = json.PROMO.BUNDLES[i][j]
        //console.log(j + " " + obj[j]);   
    }
    array.push(obj);
}
json.PROMO.BUNDLES = array;
console.log(json.PROMO.BUNDLES);
```